# InvalidOperationException when Clicking a Tab and Calling Parallel.Invoke?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety, task

**Background**

I am a person who is very new to doing threading/concurrent operations in C#, and am struggling with cross-threaded GUI applications. Right now I am experiencing an exception being thrown at run-time that I am not sure how to deal with. First, I will provide a background of what's going on, and then I will describe what I have tried to debug this.

I have a task that does a bunch of calculations.

```
readingDumpTask = new Task(() =>
{
    this.myDumpEntries = BiteDump.GetEntriesFromFile(fileName);
});
```

When this task is completed, I want to do two things at once. I implement this process, in the following way...

```
// display dump information
displayDumpTask = readingDumpTask.ContinueWith(
    delegate
    {
        Parallel.Invoke
        (
            () => this.DisplayEntries(),
            () => this.DisplayDump()
        );
    }
, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The two methods that are being delegated, work in the following way...

*Method #1*

```
private void DisplayEntries()
{
    UpdateUIDelegate myDel = new UpdateUIDelegate(this.DisplayEntries);

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(myDel);
    }

    // fills some data into labels on the GUI
}
```

*Method #2*

```
private void DisplayDump()
{
    UpdateUIDelegate myDel = new UpdateUIDelegate(this.DisplayDump);

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(myDel);
    }

    // fills some data into a RTB on the GUI
}
```

I would like to make it clear that none of the controls being used by method #1, are ever touched by method #2.

**Problem Statement**

The problem here, is that I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` as soon as I try to access the controls from inside of the `DisplayDump` function. I only ever get this exception when I have clicked on the *Dump* tab as shown below.

[image: Form Design]

I think that this has something to do with the fact that the `DisplayDump` method is accessing the text-box sitting inside the *Dump* tab. Now, when I am on the *Navigation* tab, I never experience any problems and everything works safe/sound.

**Attempted Debugging**

I have only just this morning discovered how to even see the *Parallel Tasks Debug Window* let alone really know how to use it to solve my problems. So, I have removed one of the method calls from the *Parallel.Invoke* block and I see that it doesn't matter which tab I am on, I will never get the exception in this case (`DisplayDump` always works). However, as soon as I have both actions inside of the `Parallel` statement, the problem occurs. So... So far all I know is that it has something to do with the `Parallel.Invoke`.

[image]

Comment: Btw, there is absolutely no need to use `Parallel.Invoke` for such methods, because `BeginInvoke` will serialize them on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm not so sure, parallel invoke puts the actions on separate processors. I've tested this functionality myself. When you say "serialize them on the UI" you're making it sound like the actions get performed one after another. I don't want to misunderstand you, can you please elaborate?

Comment: When the methods call `BeginInvoke`, the delegate is scheduled on the UI thread. Then the UI thread will execute the scheduled delegates one after another, one at the time.

Comment: @IvanStoev So you recommend just taking it out, and somehow have two actions in there?

Comment: If they are pure UI (like yours), yes. And btw, in that case you'll not need `BeginInvoke` because `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` will ensure the continuation is run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call BeginInvoke, your method should return.  If you fall through without a return, then the GUI will be accessed on a non-UI thread and you will get an InvalidOperationException.

```
private void DisplayEntries()
{
    UpdateUIDelegate myDel = new UpdateUIDelegate(this.DisplayEntries);

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(myDel);
        return;  // ** change here
    }

    // fills some data into labels on the GUI
}
```

Comment: Ahh right... So is that why in my debug window, there is a different "Thread Assignment" number for `DisplayDump` than for `DisplayEntries` and `ButtonClick` (shown in my bottom image)?